# Why does SLF4 not show DEBUG messages from JUL FINER message?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, java.util.logging

We are converting from using JUL logging to SLF4J logging. But some of our JARs use JUL logging.  When using the SLF4JBridgeHandler we noticed that some our messages we expected to show up did not work as expected.

Specifically messages writer to FINER did not show when we turned on DEBUG in SL4J for JAR.

Here is the documentation from SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:

```
 FINEST  -> TRACE
 FINER   -> **DEBUG**
 FINE    -> DEBUG
 INFO    -> INFO
 WARNING -> WARN
 SEVERE  -> ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on SLF4JBridgeHandler is **wrong.**

Here is the additional code from SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:

```
  private static final int TRACE_LEVEL_THRESHOLD = Level.FINEST.intValue();
  private static final int DEBUG_LEVEL_THRESHOLD = Level.FINE.intValue();
  private static final int INFO_LEVEL_THRESHOLD = Level.INFO.intValue();
  private static final int WARN_LEVEL_THRESHOLD = Level.WARNING.intValue();
```

Documentation should have looked like this:

```
 FINEST  -> TRACE
 FINER   -> **TRACE**
 FINE    -> DEBUG
 INFO    -> INFO
 WARNING -> WARN
 SEVERE  -> ERROR
```

Here is the additional code from SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:

```
  protected void callPlainSLF4JLogger(Logger slf4jLogger, LogRecord record) {
    String i18nMessage = getMessageI18N(record);
    int julLevelValue = record.getLevel().intValue();
    if (julLevelValue <= TRACE_LEVEL_THRESHOLD) {
      slf4jLogger.trace(i18nMessage, record.getThrown());
    } else if (julLevelValue <= DEBUG_LEVEL_THRESHOLD) {
      slf4jLogger.debug(i18nMessage, record.getThrown());
    } else if (julLevelValue <= INFO_LEVEL_THRESHOLD) {
      slf4jLogger.info(i18nMessage, record.getThrown());
    } else if (julLevelValue <= WARN_LEVEL_THRESHOLD) {
      slf4jLogger.warn(i18nMessage, record.getThrown());
    } else {
      slf4jLogger.error(i18nMessage, record.getThrown());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you pass this info on to the SLF4J team?